# Force Facebook Audience Network to display video ads?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-audience-network, facebook-sdk-4.x

Recently, i have tested the facebook audience network into a sample app. Everything work fine include the interstitial and native ad. However, my company need to me to just display the video ad to take advantage on the new function click to play (interstitial) and auto play(native) video ad.

Can i force the facebook audience network to just display video ad?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option to request only video ads is not currently supported. ~Vicky

Comment: Can you share the source from where you are referring this?